# Locator goes out of the graph region

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I run the following code

```
pMin = {-3, -3};
pMax = {3, 3};
range = {pMin, pMax};
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[
  {
   {Graphics[Locator[p], PlotRange -> range]},
   {Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}]]}
   }, Frame -> All
  ],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I expect the Locator control to be within the bounds of the first Graph, but instead it can be moved around the whole GraphicsGrid region. Is there an error in my code?

I also tried

```
{{p, {1, 1}}, pMin, pMax, Locator}
```

instead of

```
{{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
```

But it behaves completely wrong.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone, this is my final solution:

```
Manipulate[
 distr1 = BinormalDistribution[p1, {1, 1}, \[Rho]1];
 distr2 = BinormalDistribution[p2, {1, 1}, \[Rho]2];
 Grid[
  {
   {Graphics[{Locator[p1], Locator[p2]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]},
   {Plot3D[{PDF[distr1, {x, y}], PDF[distr2, {x, y}]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]}
   }],
 {{\[Rho]1, 0}, -0.9, 0.9}, {{\[Rho]2, 0}, -0.9, 0.9},
 {{p1, {1, 1}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**UPDATE**

Now the problem is that I cannot resize and rotate the lower 3d graph. Does anyone know how to fix that? 
I'm back to the solution with two Slider2D objects.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just place the line inside a `LocatorPane[]`?  That would have allowed you to make the locator sit precisely on the location where it has an effect, namely, the end of the line segment.

Comment: @David Carraher It's only a small example. In my notebook a need two locators which will chose two pairs of x and y coordinates for the means of two Binormal distributions which will be shown on a 3d graph. So these should be two separate graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.  There are a number of problems I see, but I don't know what to address.  Perhaps you just want a simple `Slider2D` construction?

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 1}}, 
 Column@{Slider2D[Dynamic[p], {{-3, -3}, {3, 3}}, 
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}], 
   Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[p]}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]}]
```

---

This is a reply to the updated question about 3D graphic rotation.

I believe that LocatorPane as suggested by David is a good way to approach this.  I just put in a generic function since your example would not run on Mathematica 7.

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{-1, 3}, {1, 1}}},
 Column[{
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
     Framed@Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]],
   Dynamic@
    Plot3D[{x^2 pt[[1, 1]] + y^2 pt[[1, 2]],
           -x^2 pt[[2, 1]] - y^2 pt[[2, 1]]},
        {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
 }]
]
```

Comment: I did use two Slider2D objects, but I'd rather have two locators on the same graph.

Answer (score 7):

If you examine the InputForm you'll find that GraphicsGrid returns a Graphics object.  Thus, the Locator indeed moves throughout the whole image.

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[Circle[]]}, {Graphics[Disk[]]}}] // InputForm
```

If you just change the GraphicsGrid to a Grid, the locator will be restricted to the first part but the result still looks a bit odd.  Your PlotRange specification is a bit strange; it doesn't seem to correspond to any format specified in the Documentation center.  Perhaps you want something like the following.

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{
   {Graphics[Locator[p], Axes -> True,
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]},
   {Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], Axes -> True,
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]}},
  Frame -> All],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: I up-voted this, but you don't need `Locator` in the first `Graphics` chunk; it is redundant.

Comment: Indeed, Max used some kind of rectangle specification (BL,TR) for range whereas mma uses an {xrange, yrange} specification

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, do you mean the one at `Graphics[Locator[p],Axes-> True...`. I think it is necessary, removing it creates an error for me. Seems to be necessary for the way manipulate evaluates things. Could you explain what you meant by that comment?

Comment: @dbjohn `Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> ...` is adequate.  Within `Manipulate` the line `{{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}` is already generating a locator; you do not need to do it twice.

Answer (score 6):

`LocatorPane[]` does a nice job of confining the locator to a region.

This is a variation on the method used by Mr. Wizard.

```
Column[{ LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt3],
   Framed@Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> 150, PlotRange -> 3]],
   Framed@Graphics[{Line[{{-1, 0}, Dynamic@pt3}]}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}, 
     PlotRange -> 3]}]
```

[image: locator confined]

I would have assumed that you'd want the locator to share the space with the line it controls.  In fact, to be "attached" to the line. This turns out to be even easier to implement.

```
Column[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt3],Framed@Graphics[{Line[{{-1, 0}, Dynamic@pt3}]},
 ImageSize -> 150, PlotRange -> 3]]}]
```

[image: locator on the line]

Comment: Actually I wanted to have two graphs. One 2d to select a pair of x and y coordinates and the second one is 3d to show two  binomial distributions with means that correspond to locator coordinates. But your solution works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @belisarius I do that sort of thing all the time.